# how to make the dot appear in different languages ​xamarin c#

Tags: xamarin.android

I would like to make it so that when a period is written on the phone, it is not only in English, but also in several other languages. After all, when I write a dot on them, it doesn’t work. I tried adding languages ​​via Cultureinfo. And also put a split dot for languages, but it doesn’t help. Here is the code:

```
namespace AppAndroid
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        EditText qEditText, wEditText, eEditText, rEditText, cEditText;
        Button button;
        TextView resultTextView;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.main_activity_layout);

            qEditText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.qEditText);
            wEditText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.wEditText);
            eEditText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.eEditText);
            rEditText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.rEditText);
            cEditText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.cEditText);
            button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button);
            resultTextView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.resultTextView);

            List<string> dimensionOptions = new List<string>
            {
                "Виберіть к-ть вимірів",
                "3 виміри",
                "4 виміри"
            };

            ArrayAdapter<string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, dimensionOptions);
            adapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);

            Spinner dimensionSpinner = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.dimensionSpinner);
            dimensionSpinner.Adapter = adapter;
            dimensionSpinner.ItemSelected += DimensionSpinner_ItemSelected;

            button.Click += Button_Click;
        }

        private void DimensionSpinner_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
        {
            Spinner spinner = (Spinner)sender;
            if (e.Position == 0)
            {
                rEditText.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            }
            else if (e.Position == 1)
            {
                rEditText.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            }
            else if (e.Position == 2)
            {
                rEditText.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            }
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Spinner dimensionSpinner = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.dimensionSpinner);
            int selectedPosition = dimensionSpinner.SelectedItemPosition;

            switch (selectedPosition)
            {
                case 1: 
                    CalculateForA3();
                    break;
                case 2: 
                    CalculateForA4();
                    break;
                default:
                    ShowError("Виберіть скільки вимірів!");
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void CalculateForA3()
        {
            if (double.TryParse(qEditText.Text, out double q) &&
                double.TryParse(wEditText.Text, out double w) &&
                double.TryParse(eEditText.Text, out double e) &&
                double.TryParse(cEditText.Text, out double c))
            {
                double aver = (q + w + e) / 3;
                resultTextView.Text = $"<x>={aver}";

                double delta1 = q - aver;
                double delta2 = w - aver;
                double delta3 = e - aver;
                double delta1Squared = delta1 * delta1;
                double delta2Squared = delta2 * delta2;
                double delta3Squared = delta3 * delta3;

                double aversqrt = (delta1Squared + delta2Squared + delta3Squared) / 3;
                UpdateResultText(aversqrt, c, aver);
            }
            else
            {
                ShowError("Введіть коректні значення!");
            }
        }

        private void CalculateForA4()
        {
            if (double.TryParse(qEditText.Text, out double q) &&
                double.TryParse(wEditText.Text, out double w) &&
                double.TryParse(eEditText.Text, out double e) &&
                double.TryParse(rEditText.Text, out double r) &&
                double.TryParse(cEditText.Text, out double c))
            {
                double aver = (q + w + e + r) / 4;
                resultTextView.Text = $"<x>={aver}";

                double delta1 = q - aver;
                double delta2 = w - aver;
                double delta3 = e - aver;
                double delta4 = r - aver;
                double delta1Squared = delta1 * delta1;
                double delta2Squared = delta2 * delta2;
                double delta3Squared = delta3 * delta3;
                double delta4Squared = delta4 * delta4;

                double aversqrt = (delta1Squared + delta2Squared + delta3Squared + delta4Squared) / 4;
                UpdateResultText(aversqrt, c, aver);
            }
            else
            {
                ShowError("Введіть коректні значення!");
            }
        }

        private bool TryParseDouble(string input, out double result)
        {
            return double.TryParse(input, out result);
        }

        private void UpdateResultText(double aversqrt, double c, double aver)
        {
            StringBuilder resultBuilder = new StringBuilder(resultTextView.Text);

            resultBuilder.Append("\n\n");
            resultBuilder.Append("<Δ^2>=").Append(aversqrt).Append("\n\n");
            resultBuilder.Append("σ скв.=").Append(Math.Sqrt(aversqrt / 2)).Append("\n\n");
            resultBuilder.Append("Δo=").Append((Math.Sqrt(aversqrt / 2)) * 4.3).Append("\n\n");
            double f = (double)(Math.Sqrt(aversqrt / 2) * 4.3);
            resultBuilder.Append("Δ=").Append(f + c).Append("\n\n");
            resultBuilder.Append("E=").Append((f + c) / aver);

            resultTextView.Text = resultBuilder.ToString();
        }

        private void ShowError(string message)
        {
            resultTextView.Text = message;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use the [Android Localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/localization) to make the dot appear in different languages ​xamarin c#.